# LXDE: Switch Tool Bar Menu and Desktop Right Click Menu Around

Tags: menu, lxde, openbox

On my desktop I currently have a right click menu that looks like:

[image: right click LXDE menu]

However, I want to have the full system menu that looks like this show up:

[image: LXDE system menu]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really looking for obm-xdg.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openbox#Obm-xdg

I'm using it as a pipe menu and calling it with this command:

obm-xdg /etc/xdg/menus/lxde-applications.menu

Here's the manpage.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/obm-xdg.1.html

You can use any .menu file, so feel free to try gnome.menu or debian.menu too.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on Desktop > Desktop Preferences > Advanced > chekbox [Show menu bla-bla...]

Comment: I couldn't vote this down because my reputation is not sufficient, however this is not what the user is seeking. The first picture shows what the user is experiencing WITH that a check in Desktop > Desktop Preferences > Advanced > chekbox [Show menu...]